# Type '(activeTabIndex: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => number'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass to props my function from the main parent to his second child . These 3 components are : Tabs , PageHero and BIM . BIM is the main parent and then is PageHero and after that is Tabs component. I'm trying to pass a variable and a function from BIM to there two. When I'm trying to create my function in BIM component I get the error from the title.
Here is the components code:

Tabs:

```js
interface Props {
  firstTabContent?: React.ReactNode;
  secondTabContent?: React.ReactNode;
  onChange?: () => number;
  activeTabIndex?: number;
}

const Tabs = ({
  firstTabContent,
  secondTabContent,
  onChange,
  activeTabIndex,
}: Props) => {
  // const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState<number>(1);

  return (
    <div className="c-tabs">
      <ul className="c-tabs__list">
        <li className="c-tabs__item">
          <button
            onClick={onChange}
            className={
              activeTabIndex === 1 ? "c-tabs__btn" : "c-tabs__btn--active"
            }
          >
            Tab 1
          </button>
        </li>
```

Here is PageHero:

```js
import Tabs from "./Tabs/Tabs";

export interface Props {
  title?: string;
  date?: string;
  description?: string;
  entries?: string;
  onChange?: () => number;
  activeTabIndex?: number;
}

const PageHero: React.FC<Props> = ({
  title,
  date,
  entries,
  description,
  onChange,
  activeTabIndex,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="pagehero">
        <div className="pagehero__container">
          <div className="pagehero__text">
            <h1 className="pagehero__title">{title}</h1>
            <div className="pagehero__container-date">
              <p className="pagehero__date">{date}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="pagehero__container-links">
            <Tabs
              firstTabContent="ccc"
              secondTabContent="aaa"
              onChange={onChange}
              activeTabIndex={activeTabIndex}
            />
```

And the main parrent is :

```js
import "./Bim.css";

export interface Props {}

const Bim: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState<number>(1);

  function handleTabClick(activeTabIndex: number) {
    setActiveTabIndex(activeTabIndex);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <PageHero
        title="BEST INNOVATIVE MINDS 2021"
        date="OPEN ● 24days, 12h, 41mins Remaining"
        description="Description"
        entries="Entries"
        onChange={handleTabClick}
      />
```

On the BIM component I get this error :

**Type '(activeTabIndex: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => number'.ts(2322)
PageHero.tsx(12, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props**

from my  onChange={handleTabClick} prop in the PageHero component. I don't know so much about typescript and I hope that you can  write  a explicit  answear .

Comment: `onChange` expects to call a function with no parameters which returns a number. You give it a function with a number as a parameter that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The prop signature should be `onChange?: (x:number) => void` in `Props`;

Because your handler isn't returning anything
and assuming the signature of `onChange` in `Tabs` is the same, i.e. takes a `number` argument and returns `void`

Also your tabs component needs modification
 `onClick={onChange}` prob needs to be more like  `onClick={()=>onChange(activeTabIndex)}`

Comment: did this help or would you like further clarification?